# Can polymorphism be simulated by lazy type operators?

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory, types-and-programming-languages

In the definition of [lambda cubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_cube), type polymorphism is distinguished from type operators/constructors.

I have the nagging feeling that type polymorphism can be constructed through type operators using lazyness. This may be extremely convoluted but I always felt polymorphic types where just functioning "as if" waiting for a concrete type.

Here's an example...

Take `(+1)::Num a => a -> a`, `(+1) pi` is `Floating` whilst `(+1) 1.1` is `Fractional`.

This level of polymorphism above can be constructed through the use of a "universal delayed type constructor" `F` and a type operator `G` designed for `(+1)`. Where,

`F :: X -> f -> a -> X a`

I've tried to upper case type signatures to represent types and lower case for terms.

And where,
`G :: a -> B
G ( _ ::Integral) = Integral
G ( _ ::Fractional) = Fractional
G ( _ ::Floating) = Floating`

Note that G's implementation is partial, I've not actually said how `(+1)::Floating -> Floating`  is implemented differently from `(+1)::Integral -> Integral` .

Therefore, `F G (+1)` achieves the same as `(+1)` with polymorphism above. This is a simple example, I may need to go a second level (i.e. operators on type operators) to simulate polymorphic type operators.

So, is true that polymorphism can be simulated by type operators? I'm probably wrong but I don't understand why. Can anyone help?

[EDIT]

My question was ill-posed. I didn't have the concept quite formed in my mind. It actually was triggered by Pierce's comment

> when a polymorphic function meets a type argument, the type is actually substituted into the body of the function.

Based on that, polymorphic functions felt very close to type operators: type operators work on types, polymorphic functions crystalize into proper functions when given a type. I felt that polymorphic types could be replaced by some kind of (recursive) type operator that "fetched" the proper type. I forgot however that polymorphic types have kind $*$ whilst type operators have kind $* \rightarrow *$. So that's at least one difference.

Comment: Note that you can use Markdown here.

Comment: Note that in [logical frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_framework), you can *encode* $\Pi$-types as a constructor: $\texttt{Π}$, which is applied to a function: $\Pi x:A.\ B = \texttt{Π}(\lambda x:A.\ B)$. Unfortunately, you still need dependent types at the *framework level*.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me how your idea is supposed to work, but everything you're doing can just simply be done with a bit of more high-powered type theory. That is, if we allow quantification over types then we can talk about polymorphism. Let's go from easy examples to the ones you're talking about.

A function such as
$$f \, x = (x,x)$$
is polymorphic in the type of $x$: if $x$ has type $A$ then $f$ has type $A \to A \times A$. We can express this sort of dependency by intrducing an extra argument so that $f$ has type $\prod_{A : \mathsf{Type}} A \to A \times A$ and is defined by
$$f \, A \, x = (x, x).$$

Your example is like this, except a bit more complicated. To keep examples simple, let me instead used a simplified class (the whole `Num` is a bit large)

```
class Cow a where
  one :: a
  plus :: a -> a -> a
```

and consider a functio dependent on `Cow`:

```
plusOne :: Cow a => a -> a
plusOne x = plus x one
```

We can express `plusOne` as before, except that now it takes *three* extra parameters: a type $A$, an element of $A$, and a function $A \to A \to A$. So its type would be
$$
\prod_{A : \mathsf{Type}} A \to (A \to A \to A) \to A \to A
$$
and it would be defined by
$$\mathtt{plusOne} \; A \; \mathtt{one} \; \mathtt{plus} \; x =
  \mathtt{plus} \; x \; \mathtt{one}.$$
This is a general trick: polymorphism can always be replaced by passing around extra arguments, but the price you pay is that you will have *dependent* types and there might be many extra arguments.